# If $\omega$ is the differential of $f$, then $\int_a^b c^* \omega = f(c(b)) - f(c(a))$.

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, solution-verification

**Problem.** 
Let $c: [a,b] \rightarrow X$ be a smooth curve and let $c(a) = p, c(b) = q$. Show that if $\omega$ is the differential of a function on $X$, $\omega = df$, then $\int_a^b c^* \omega = f(q) - f(p)$.

**My Attempt.** 
Let $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be any function so that $df = \omega$. Define $F: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so that $F(t) = (f \circ c)(t)$. Note that $F(b) = f(c(b)) = f(q)$ and $F(a) = f(c(a)) = f(p)$. Because $f$ has a differential, $f$ must be differentiable, and $c$ is smooth, so the function $F$ is the composition of differentiable functions and is therefore differentiable with derivative $F'(t) = (f \circ c)'(t) = df_{c(t)} (c'(t))$ per the chain rule. But, per the definition of the pull back, we have $(c^*\omega)_t = (c^*df)_t = df_{c(t)} (c'(t))$. Thus, we have $c^*\omega = F'(t)$ and therefore, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have $\int_a^b c^* \omega = \int_a^b F'(t) = F(b) - F(a) = f(q) - f(p)$.

**Comments.** 
I think I have the right idea, but I don't know if the notation is correct. And maybe I really, really don't have the right idea. I'm sorry if my attempt is incomprehensibly stupid; I feel like I'm really close to getting this stuff, but I'm just not quite there!

Comment: Looks good to me.